# Best way to use shared sources in Typescript projects?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm working on a project using Angular4 as front-end and NodeJS written in Typescript as back-end.

I would like to use some ts sources between both sides (DTO-like for instance) but I don't know how to handle it the best way. They do use some external dependencies.

I have 3 folders: client/, server/ and common/.

- Should the common folder (containing the common ts sources) have its own package.json?
- Where should the compiled .js files go? In common/dest/? If so, will the imports work well when running the app (client + server)?

I'm using Grunt for my Node typescript sources to compile them and angular-cli (with npm start) for my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be treat the common code like a package (which you may even decide to to literally so you could version it - i.e. in a private NPM feed).

Even if you don't make an NPM package, you can follow most of the steps to make your usage as easy as possible.

1. Compile the common code with definitions switched on (`--declaration`)
2. Compile using `UMD` modules, so the same modules will work on Node and in the browser
3. Copy the `.js` and `.d.ts` files to where you need to consume them

If you go "full package", change the third step to copy the files into the distribution folder to be packaged.

The general idea would be to keep a single "source of truth" set of TypeScript files, and wherever you copy the code to just gets JavaScript and type definitions.

Comment: this is still nowhere near as useful as a C# project, where I can add a class library and enjoy. This is a serious drawback of Node imo

Answer (score 0):

Make a package where you export your library in "./index.ts"

package.json

```
{
   //...
   "main": "./build/index.js",
   "typings": "./build/index"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      //...
      "declaration": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./build"
   },
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "build"
   ]
}
```

Push your code to github and install it by using npm, `npm install github:[username]/[repository]#[master/tag]`

For example https://github.com/tfso/njs-tfso-repository is a npm package of a typescript library, where the release tag contains the transpiled javascript (the github source does not include javascript). This can be installed by typing `npm install tfso/njs-tfso-repository#1.2.98`

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a simple project with a `client / server/ shared` structure, then you can alter your `tsconfig.json` to include `"compilerOptions" : { "rootDir": "../." }`.